# Using PHP on non-supportive server

Tags: php, flash

I have a rather complicated scenario that I have never really had to deal with before.  I am creating a website that will be hosted on a web-server without PHP support.  But I need to call a PHP script that returns a Flash Slideshow.  Is there any way that I can do this? Here is the bit of PHP code that I need to call to return the Flash Slideshow.

```
<?php

//include slideshow.php to access the Insert_Slideshow function
include "http://mywebsite/slideshow.php";

//insert the slideshow.swf flash file into the web page
//tell slideshow.swf to get the slideshow's data from sample.php created in the first step
//set the slideshow's width to 320 pixels and the height to 240
echo Insert_Slideshow ( "http://mywebsite/slideshow.swf", "http://mywebsite/sample.php", 600, 500 );

?>
```

Comment: Can't you embed the flash object from a remote server that supports PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you obviously can't run PHP on a server that doesn't have it, if your slideshow doesn't change frequently perhaps you could run your PHP script on another machine, capture the output, then upload that to your web host.

Comment: Brilliant mate,  should have thought of that.  Simply ran it locally and grabbed the OBJECT class and popped it into my non-supportive PHP site.  Worked like a champ.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

To run PHP on your server (not another server) you will definitely need to install a PHP processor.

However since you have a hard-coded URL in there, it looks as though the PHP code is just some kind of utility function for inserting a flash movie.

Run the PHP code on your local computer (for example) and see what HTML it generates, and if it always generates that same HTML, why not just copy it and use that in your website.

Answer (score 1):

You could have the PHP script execute on a PHP enabled webserver somewhere else and include it in an iframe on the page without PHP support. That would be quite ugly, tho.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. If you need to call a PHP script, its obvious that you need PHP installed on the web server.